# Error : AppDomain mssqlsystemresource.sys[runtime].149 was unloaded by escalation policy to ensure the consistency of your application

Tags: sql-server

While I am Converting a varchar value to GEOGRAPHY I am getting error like this.

Msg 6533, Level 16, State 48, Line 1
AppDomain mssqlsystemresource.sys[runtime].149 was unloaded by escalation policy to ensure the consistency of your application. Out of memory happened while accessing a critical resource. 
The application domain in which the thread was running has been unloaded.

Query I executed is

```
DECLARE @WKT VARCHAR(2000)= 'POINT(-73.0464 40.8131)'
SELECT convert(GEOGRAPHY ,WKT)
```

It was working fine earlier.
My Version is MSSQL Server 2008 R2(RTM)

Answer (score 0):

I got the Answer. My server RAM capacity was 4GB. I increased it to 16GB. Issue Resolved. So I realized that RAM Space Issue.